# Importing mutliple contacts (with Birthday) from file into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, import, contacts

I need to import mutliple contacts (over 1000) with birthday date into Outlook 2007/2010 (Exchange 2003 underneath) and then create an entry in calendar according to that birthday date. File from which it will be imported can either be CVS or EXCEL or any kind of file that can be easily prepared in Excel.

Is there a program to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can format your Excel file to fit the correct CSV Export format of Microsoft Outlook.
It's a format where every Item is marked by Quotes, e.g.

```
"Birthday"
```

The Header is too long for me to paste, but just go to Outlook, File, Import/Export and export your calendar and your contacts into a file. This will give you a template on what columns you need. Formatting Excel Sheets that way will enable you to export CSV files you can import in Outlook, if everything works ok.

Comment: Seems to be working fine! :-) What about creating an entry in calendar from imported contacts?

Comment: Adding a Calendar Entry works pretty  much the same way. A recurring Entry with the name "BirthdayTest Person1" for today, yearly, all day, would result in a csv-entry like this:
"BirthdayTest Person1","2.3.2011","00:00:00","3.3.2011","00:00:00","True","True","1.3.2011","06:00:00",,,,,,,"
","",,"Normal","False","Normal","3"

Again, Export your Calendar File to get an Idea for the header. You can use Excel to automatically populate your Outlook Calendar Sheet with Data from the Contact Sheet, and create a CSV file to export

Comment: After importing running `outlook /cleanreminders` seems to do the trick of inserting all contacts birthday dates as reminders. As per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286166 recommendation.